# New variable with same density under change of measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, density-function

If $X$ is a random variable defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ endowed with the Borel sigma-algebra and the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. X has a density, $f$.

For $k>0$, consider the density

$$g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=a\times f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)e^{-k\sum_{m=1}^nx_i}$$

where $a$ is a normalizing constant. $g$ defines a new random variable $Y$.

Now, could I say that the density of $Y$ under a product measure $\mu$ is $f$, where $\mu$ uses the expression $e^{-k\sum_{m=1}^nx_i}$?

Then, $\mu$ would be a product measure, right? And thus under $\mu$, is it correct that $Y$ has all the properties of $X$ under $\lambda$? Such as dependencies etc?

I am lost with these concepts of change of measure. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^{n}$ is not a probability measure.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to edit. I'm new to this.